# How to prepend something to CLI in docker container?

Tags: docker, mono, dockerfile

I want to prepend something to the CLI passed in to a docker container.

I want it to run like this:

`docker run -it mstools msbuild.exe --version`

But, to make that work internally I need to prepend the full path the the msbuild.exe along with mono, like this:

`mono /Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.14.1.0.0-prerelease/lib/msbuild.exe --version`

When I use my below `Dockerfile` with the command, I get this:

```
$ docker run -it mstools msbuild.exe --version
msbuild.exe: 1: msbuild.exe: [/usr/bin/mono,: not found
```

If I jump into the container and check the path:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint=bash mstools
root@eb47008f092e:/# which mono
/usr/bin/mono
```

What am I missing??

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centeredge/nuget
ARG VERSION="14.1.0.0-prerelease"
RUN nuget install Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug -Version $VERSION -Source "https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-buildtools/"
ENV PATH="/Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/:${PATH}"
ENTRYPOINT ['/usr/bin/mono', " /Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/$1 $@"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get certainly comes from the fact you use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` in the `ENTRYPOINT` exec form.

In addition, I don't think the `"$@"` phrasing you mention will work (because `"$@"` needs some shell to evaluate it, while in the exec form there is no `/bin/sh -c …` implied). But the exec form of `ENTRYPOINT` is definitely the way to go.

So I'd suggest you write something like this:

```
FROM centeredge/nuget
ARG VERSION="14.1.0.0-prerelease"
RUN nuget install Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug -Version $VERSION -Source "https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-buildtools/"
ENV PATH="/Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/:${PATH}"
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/src/
RUN chmod a+x /usr/src/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/entrypoint.sh"]
```

with `entrypoint.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/mono "/Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/$1" "$@"
```

(Note: I didn't test this example code for now so please comment if you find some typo)

Comment: I don't like adding a separate file to the build if I can help it so I inlined the file creation for the entrypoint - I suspected it would be needed. You win the prize. I will post the final solution

Answer (score 1):

Final working solution based on @ErikMD's answer:

```
FROM centeredge/nuget
ARG VERSION="14.1.0.0-prerelease"
RUN nuget install Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug -Version $VERSION -Source "https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-buildtools/"
ENV PATH="/Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/:/Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/tools/:${PATH}"
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > /usr/src/entrypoint.sh && echo 'exec /usr/bin/mono "$(which "$1")" "$@"' >> /usr/src/entrypoint.sh && chmod a+x /usr/src/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/entrypoint.sh"]
```

output

```
 docker run -it mstools MSBuild.exe -version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.1.0.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

14.1.0.0
```

Comment: Glad that the proposed solution worked for you :) however note that there's a remaining quoting issue (`$1` and `$@` should always be surrounded by double quotes), and you should probably merge the two `RUN` commands. Hence the following suggested code: `RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > /usr/src/entrypoint.sh && echo 'exec /usr/bin/mono "/Microsoft.Build.Mono.Debug.$VERSION/lib/$1" "$@"' >> /usr/src/entrypoint.sh && chmod a+x /usr/src/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: FYI I've edited your answer as suggested − adding missing quotes and merging the two `RUN` commands to reduce the number of layers (feel free to react or edit further if need be)